# Using Google Gmail API for Desktop Application

Tags: python, gmail, google-oauth, gmail-api, smtplib

I have a desktop application which sends email from Gmail using SMTP.

Since [Less secure Apps](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) will not longer be supported, I am trying to use Google API with OAuth2. Is there any other way I can use to send email from Gmail accounts?

Also, if I use Google API with OAuth2 can we configure the client ID and client secret generated from Admin Gmail account and use the same for all the other users for authorization?

I am following this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44ERDGa9Dr4

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

> I have a desktop application which sends email from Gmail using SMTP. Since Less secure Apps will not longer be supported, I am trying to use Google API with OAuth2.

If you want to stick with smtp did you consider checking out Did you consider checking [Xoauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol)?

Have you tried using an [app password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) im not sure if thats going away as well.

> Can we configure the client ID and client secret generated from Admin Gmail account and use the same for all the other users for authorization?

If you have a google workspace domain, Then you could use a service account and set up [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) which would allow the [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account) to impersonate any user on your domain.

If these are standard google gmail email accounts then you will need to use oauth2 to request consent from each user.

## verification

remember if you switch to Oauth2 you will need to have your app [verified](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en)

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you for all your suggestion, I will try them.
Also, I am not working with a google workspace domain, by admin I meant like a developer gmail account which will be used to create the app and generate ClientID/Client Secret. They are standard gmail accounts, and its fine if I have to request consent from each user, just will the oauth2 credentials work for all the users if hardcoded?

Comment: The user needs to authorize your app, then you can store the refresh token.  You can use the refresh token at a later date to request a new access token which will give you access to the users account via the gmail api.    Remember that verification for a gmail restricted scope is going to cost between $15k - $75k each year for the security audit.

Comment: @DalmTo, Is the verification compulsory? Also Is there any other way than Gmail Api?

Comment: not always if its a single user app for example it shouldn't need to be verified but you need to apply and they will tell you.  You should read though [Verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914#verification-types&zippy=%2Cwhat-are-the-different-types-of-verification-that-google-requires-for-accessing-user-data-via-oauth) or  watch this [What you need to know about application verification](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzIuNmNX9N8)

Comment: @DalmTo, I need to just send Email from client's email id and it is a Desktop software, not a mobile application. Based on what i read, I dont think verification will be mandatory for my case.